# Open new window when you click play in jwplayer 5

Tags: javascript, html, jwplayer

Old example is megavideo.com.....when you click play button once, it will open a new window to a sponsor site. then it will play the video.

Can this be done in jw player 5?

Player code:

```
<div id="mediaplayer">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="player.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="player.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
            flashplayer: "player.swf",
            provider:'http',
            file: "file.mp4",
            screencolor: "000000",
            width: "875",
            height: "480",
            skin: "/player/skins/glow.zip",
            plugins: {
            'timeslidertooltipplugin-3': {}
            }

        });
        </script>
        </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: You could use the API and onPlay - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw5/31164/javascript-api-reference

Comment: How? Can you explain me? Thanks

Comment: I try this jwplayer('mediaplayer').onPlay(function() { window.open('http://www.google.com'); }); but browsers block it as popup :(

Comment: Well yes, pop up blockers will detect window.open. In JW5 you can set a variable called displayclick to link and then set the link variable to the link you want.

Comment: Can you give me an example? Thanks in advance

Comment: Example - http://bit.ly/1bvYhVf

Comment: Thanks for the example is opening without blocking but the video not playing why?

Comment: Because making the click action = open a link overrides the default play action. You could always set autostart to true, too.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your player object in a div, set the position to absolute i believe, then do another div inside after your player object with the position to relative and top to 0, left, 0, right 0, bottom 0 (should theoretically expand the inner div to inside, then add a click event on it to open your window and hide it div.

This is basically called an overlay ontop of your player.

**Update**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="mediaplayer"></div>
    <div class="overlay">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<style>
  .container {
        position : relative;
        width : 258px;
        height : 203px;
  }

  .overlay {
      position : absolute;
      top : 0;
      left : 0;
      right : 0;
      bottom : 0;
      cursor : pointer;
  }
  </style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="player.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
            flashplayer: "player.swf",
            provider:'http',
            file: "file.mp4",
            screencolor: "000000",
            width: "875",
            height: "480",
            skin: "/player/skins/glow.zip",
            plugins: {
            'timeslidertooltipplugin-3': {}
            }

        });

        $('.overlay').click(function() {
                 window.open("http://www.google.com");
                 jwplayer("mediaplayer").play(true);
                 $(this).hide();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Can i have an example? With the player code that i just added above..? Thanks

Comment: But this just an image of the player? I want that the player continu to play the video after openning the window...

Comment: jwplayer should have some remote calls you can do to start the video. Judging by this URL http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference you should be able to put jwplayer("mediaplayer").play(true); in the click function of jquery to start your video. What i gave you in that jsfiddle is a concept, not the exact code to do what you want.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, jsfiddle doesn't have access to your library of code. But, I'll update my answer to show you a more accurate answer.

Comment: Nothing is opening with the code that you gave me...any idea why?

Comment: Did you copy the CSS from the jsfiddle over?

Comment: Updated the css in the answer.

Comment: Yes i did even i copy paste your updated code with the css and still not working otherwise <div id="mediaplayer"></div> if we leave like that the player wouldn't show up the div need to surround the player script...But the link is not opening when i click on the video...